# how to associate users having specific attribute and users in role ? net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to get users list having role Admin and not being locked or blocked. Could you help me?

```
(_userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin")).Result.Where((_userManager.Users.Where(u => u.LockoutEnabled == false)));

    (_userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin")).Result.Where((_userManager.Users.Where(u => u.UserAccountIsBlocked == UserAccountIsBlocked.No)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For querying `User Role` and other properties, you could try linq like below:

```
            var query = from user in _context.Users
                    join userRole in _context.UserRoles on user.Id equals userRole.UserId
                    join role in _context.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                    where user.LockoutEnabled == false
                    //&& user.UserAccountIsBlocked == UserAccountIsBlocked.No
                    && role.NormalizedName == "Admin"
                    select user;
        var users = query.ToList();
```

You could add the other query condition based on your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you defined the porperty UserAccountIsBlocked. So:

`(await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin")).Where(u=> u.UserAccountIsBlocked == UserAccountIsBlocked.No && u.LockoutEnabled==false));`